# whast the diff betn gradle Module and gradle Project in andorid Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

[image]

Hello  guys ,  actually Im little bit confused in the gradle files structure.
whats the diff betn

build.gradle(project: app_name)
build.gradle(module: app_name)

and below listed other files .

Thanks a lot for having a look .
any extra knowledge and information is deeply appriciated

Answer (score 1):

From the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build#build-files)

> The top-level build.gradle file, located in the root project directory, defines build configurations that apply to all modules in your project. By default, the top-level build file uses the buildscript block to define the Gradle repositories and dependencies that are common to all modules in the project.

With few words you have always one in your root directory and it's used to define the settings for every module of your app

> The module-level build.gradle file, located in each project/module/ directory, allows you to configure build settings for the specific module it is located in. Configuring these build settings allows you to provide custom packaging options, such as additional build types and product flavors, and override settings in the main/ app manifest or top-level build.gradle file.

Here you can simply specify the properties of the single module such as the dependency version and the minimum android sdk version

I think one way to better understand the concept is to deal with a [multi-module app](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-app-module)
In large projects this approach has many advantages such as the separation of concepts and the simplification of teamwork.